# What can you do if you have answered a question correctly and the asker insists it doesn't work?

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new here, but I knew the answer to a question and put some effort into providing a helpful answer including some sample code.  After the asker said it didn't work, I went back and tested it again, using his sample input and got back the results that he said he wanted.  He accepted the answer and then later he said it didn't work and unaccepted the answer.

Apparently asking for punishment, I went back again and changed the formatting a bit to make it very clear what was going on and tried to explain even more.

I know the accepted answer thing is supposed to be for whether the answer is helpful to the asker.  However my answer does work and solves the issue as he described it. I'm assuming the issue is somewhere in the code he hasn't shared. Shouldn't the asker acknowledge that the problem is outside the scope of the original question?

Comment: RUN!!!!!! You found a help vampire. Just run.

Comment: Or just walk, if you prefer. The important thing is to move *away*.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have a question open now with a bounty (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838846/cascading-dropdowns-second-one-doesnt-always-keep-change) and the person who has been helping me has no problem running my code. I don't care what I do, I can't make it work on my machine. My situation is not exactly the same as OP's, but I can assure you that I am not a help vampire. I just can't get it to work and am at a loss what to do at this point. Jen R, I wish I knew what to tell you, other than to thank you for your efforts. :)

Comment: @pixelmeow Your question's answer also isn't... much of an answer. Plenty of great answers with the working code will get a "I couldn't get this to compile because that variable you had doesn't exist". At which point, I start running, because the OP clearly doesn't have enough sense and critical thinking ability to do anything but just copy-paste my code. It sure sounds like thats what is happening here. Hence, help vampire.

Comment: There is another one where I gave the asker about 15 things to try in order to debug, and the asker said "it doesn't work" in response.  I wonder which part doesn't work?  Yikes.  Apparently I haven't learned!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET got it. I even copy-pasted what I had put in the page to make sure, and it still doesn't work... but yeah, I know what you mean. I've read nightmares here in meta. JenR, that is *definitely* a vampire!

Comment: @JenR props for trying to help so much, but you'll realize that if you "make it work", the OP will then probably change his question into something like "ok, now that THIS is working, I have THIS bug", making all your work look like useless..... uphill battle. As pointed out... just run

Comment: lol at you all identifying a HV so quickly.  Jen we've all been had - it's soul destroying, but chalk it up to experience :-)

Comment: If you ignore people after you gave a correct answer they often start to think and try things on their own. I notice this quite a lot. I answer; there is a "does not compile. what is `myFancyBoolVariable`? Help?" comment; then there is a "can you explain the code. help?" comment; then another one. And two hours later they write "i figured it out. thanks". (It might not be the nicest way to ignore askers, but it helps me, and it often helps them as well. )

Comment: there will always be those that want to be given the solution, and can't be bothered to 'give back' in any way. Some will offer the bare minimum (eventually) and others won't. The only downside to your unacknowledged help is that by asking and getting an answer, your help vampire will probably try again later and do the same thing. That's part of why you see comments like "so what have you tried?" and the like, because that's people thinking "looks like a help vampire, but lets give the benefit of the doubt".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the people over at Code Review won't appreciate an influx of help vampires. Or were you referring to the supplicants?

Comment: Do not worry too much about the score of the answer or the fact that it has been accepted or not. I found that when people try to show appreciation for my effort they pick my highest scoring answer  from my profile and vote it up. So the meaning of the score of the (my) top answer is not related to the answer (which is pretty basic) but more to appreciation. At the same time, brilliant answers often get low scores because less people are interested (niche topic). Scoring is skewed, don't worry just enjoy the ride by sharing knowledge and learning at the same time.

Comment: I did try to point this out to you, the OP thinks they have a right to help we are resource to be pulled on. The best thing you can do is walk away, I already got in a spat with him about it *(which I now see the "Meta Effect" has cleaned up)*.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Do nothing - other than double check your answer to make sure it *is* correct.

After that leave it up to the community to vote.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing nobody will notice to vote since it's an old-school classic ASP question and those don't get much attention.  Oh well :-)

Comment: Then you've just got to walk away with the knowledge that you answered the question correctly. Not every correct answer is going to get accepted, for any number of reasons.

Comment: @JenR If the question is reasonably well worded so that someone might find it on a search, and there are no better solutions on SO, yours could easily be the one that is found by everyone with that same problem.  The best questions, even if old, keep on collecting upvotes on good answers.

Comment: I just tried your solution and it does not work. :/

Comment: @Mario: Perhaps you should ask a new question of your own.