# Downvoting a Question if the Asker Poorly Manages Answers

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

Recently (and not so recently) I've come across several questions where the asker has failed, or out-right refused to select an obviously right answer.  The logic often goes along the lines of "*it answers **this** question, but it didn't really fix **my** problem*".  Worse, I've come across questions where the asker has coaxed very specific, non-broadly applicable answers that *don't* address the original issue out of overly-helpful Stack users.

Overly picky users are not new to any site on the Exchange, [nor are questions regarding what to do when your answer gets the short end of a stick unjustly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287757/what-can-you-do-if-you-have-answered-a-question-correctly-and-the-asker-insists), but I've found little in terms of what to do in these cases when the question is also of a high enough quality to stand on its own (in the above link, the selected answer suggests - "leave it up to the community"; as a minor part of the community, I'm unsure of what to do).

While this certainly doesn't hit any of the well-documented criteria for down-voting I've come across, I do feel like it can effectively lower the quality of a question; especially in the latter case.  **Is it appropriate to down-vote a question based on the author's treatment of its answers?**  Is there any action that could/should be taken?  I guess the right answer may still be attached to the question, but if an asker snuffs it, or worse, downvotes it themself in favor of a less helpful answer, how can other users appropriately respond?

Comment: If it doesn't fix the OP's problem, it is possible that the question itself is unclear in describing the problem. This could be because the OP didn't state the problem well, or some other reason that is leading to answers that are just taking stabs at the possible question. Mouse over the down vote triangle on a question read the text.

Comment: Voting should be based on your own assessment of what is useful.  But personally, I would never downvote an otherwise good question just because they didn't select an answer you think is the best one.  But as @MichaelT points out, it is also possible the question wasn't clear ernough

Comment: @MichaelT that's a very interesting way to look at it.  If the OP wanted a certain answer, a well-formed question would have made that clear.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Which is why I don't down-vote them (the punishment doesn't seem to fit the crime).  Still, MichaelT brings up a pretty solid point.

Comment: Downvoting a question because it doesn't accept an answer, and then saying the decision had to do with the question's quality seems a bit disingenious though. A good rule of thumb might be: would I have downvoted the question if the OP hadn't refused to accept an answer? If not, leave it be.

Comment: @Pekka웃 is there a better course of action?

Comment: Personally, I tend to leave a comment criticizing the quality of their question and telling the OP they might get more satisfying results if they asked a clearer question. Some take it to heart, sometimes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it is not appropriate to downvote a question because the asker doesn't accept or upvote answers.

Votes on the question are meant to vote on the quality and effort put into the question itself. They're not intended to be used as *punishment for lack of appreciation*.

If your answer to the question deserves upvotes, other users will vote it up. There is absolutely no requirement for the asker to do so, or to accept an answer at all.

With that being said: Votes are your own, and ultimately it's your decision how to use them.

I'd personally hate to see them used in that fashion, as it's not how this site was designed to function or the type of behavior that should be encouraged. We've never been a "I'm going to punish you because you won't properly show me appreciation" site; SO has always been a site for collecting knowledge and sharing information. If you're here looking solely for personal gain in the form of reputation and badges, and want to punish people who won't give them to you when you think you deserve them, you're probably on the wrong site.

Comment: This is a very good answer. "I'm going to up-vote a totally random question or answer of you, somewhere on one of the 11 SE sites you frequent, just to show my appreciation."

Comment: To be clear - I'm not talking about any questions (specifically) that I have answers on, this is a general question regarding answers more fitting to the Q and A style of the site that get snubbed.  **Still**, if you replace the instances of "*you*" in your answer with "*somebody*" it's just as good, and as informative.  Excellent reply, +1.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any thoughts on MichaelT's comment on the OP?

Comment: I meant the "you" as the royal you, as in "somebody", and not you personally. :-). "You" is easier to type. :-) Regarding @MichaelT's comment: He's absolutely right. You *should* downvote questions that deserve to be downvoted as poor quality questions (which I said in my answer here with "vote on the quality of the question"). If the question is poor quality, it should be downvoted. My opinion is that the downvote should not be used as punishment for the asker's response (or lack of) to *answers*. Votes on the question should always be based on *the question* and nothing else, IMO.

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for, thanks!